# Matching items in columns in different sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets. The first one has this structure:

```
    A       B           C
1   Name    UniqueID    yes or blank
2   Billy   422312
3   Jason   23131       yes
4   Jack    23111
5   Michele 552132
6   Fabius  287         yes
7   Abhram  87777
8   Adem    233332
9   Jo      1902        yes
```

The second one has this structure:

```
    A       B           C
1   Name    UniqueID    yes or blank
2   Jo      1902
3   Fabius  287
4   Michele 552132
5   Abhram  87777
6   Adem    233332
7   Billy   422312
```

So, I need to find a formula to put in SecondSheet:C2 that matches the UniqueID (they're not ordered in the same way in second sheet, and some are missing) and prints a `yes` if the same person has a `yes` in the first sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple VLookup

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B7, Sheet1!$B$2:$C$9,2, FALSE),""))
```

Comment: I tried but for some reason 3000 new rows are added to the doc and anyway I get the error that I need to add 1 other row.. !

Comment: What ranges are you applying the formula to